# WCF AfterReceiveRequest (member of IDispatchMessageInspector) find out request type?

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there any way in AfterReceiveRequest  method that I find out requst type(httprequest Or Soap reqest)?

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    //get request type
}
```

Comment: Do you mean http or net.tcp? SOAP can be the body of http request so they are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this myself but since nobody has given an answer I would suggest trying this:
Instead of (or in addition to) implementing `IDispatchMessageInspector`, implement [`IServiceBehavior`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) and inspect the URI Scheme in the `Validate` method:

```
public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
{
    foreach (ServiceEndpoint item in serviceDescription.Endpoints)
    {
        string theScheme = item.Binding.Scheme;
    }
}
```